# ubuntu 14.04 SuperDesk Raven not configured (logging is disabled)

Tags: ubuntu, docker, raven, superdesk

I installed a clean Ubuntu 14.04 x64 server machine on VMWare ESXi5.5
Inside it I followed the installation procedure for Sourcefabric's SuperDesk software described in https://github.com/superdesk/superdesk/blob/master/README.md

After running the 'local demo' and 'create user' script at the end of the README.md file, I get the following output:

> WARNING:elasticsearch:PUT /superdesk [status:400 request:0.064s]
>
> Raven is not configured (logging is disabled). Please see the documentation for more information.
>   INFO:raven.base.Client:Raven is not configured (logging is disabled). Please see the documentation for more information.
>
> Command finished with:  {'password': '$THE_PASSWORD_HASH.', 'is_active': True, 'user_type': 'administrator', 'needs_activation': False, 'session_preferences': {}, '_etag': 'acc4fd0363d32c1e3c283662ea6c0a8411044773', 'email': 'admin@example.com', '_updated': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 13, 15, 30, 11, tzinfo=), 'username': 'admin'}

I was wondering, as logging is very limited in syslog now, how I can get that Raven logging system installed, I can't seem to find it in my current apt repositories...

Answer (score 1):

raven is a sentry client, so if you have sentry running you can set SENTRY_DSN env var to avoid that warning, but otherwise you can just ignore it, it should work fine without it. and it doesn't mean that without it it disabled all logging, it should still be there on stderr